# iOS 8 enterprise apps are stuck in limbo inside the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

In trying to release a new update to one of my enterprise iOS apps, I'm finding that the OTA download is failing. It will give me the "Would you like to install 'xxx'" alert, and tapping 'Install' is about as far as it will go. There's no indication that anything is happening. This occurs on my iPhone 6 and iPad both running the most recent release of iOS 8.

Running the devices on the iPhone Configuration Utility, it shows the list of installed apps, and the one app that is refusing to install has an "Install" button where all the others have "Uninstall." In the screen cap below you'll see the renamed bundle and the original bundle.

[image]

When I click the "Install" button, the iPhone Configuration Utility crashes.

I managed to get it to work using a workaround that I found elsewhere on StackOverflow, which requires renaming the app's Bundle Identifier, but it still seems like a pi$$-poor way to do it.

It seems clear that the app is somehow stuck in limbo, showing up on the app list but not showing up on the iPhone screen, and also is refusing to be overwritten. My question is, is there a way to purge the old app from the iPhone's memory, and possibly reload it using the original Bundle Identifier?

Answer (score 2):

Apple still hasn't fixed this correctly in even the latest versions. There are several manifestations:  the app does download, but the device doesn't quit the calling app, so you don't know if the app downloads or not.  If the app was never on your device before, it usually downloads.  If it was there before, and was deleted, it doesn't download.  If the downloaded app is already running in the background, or you're doing in-app downloading, it often doesn't download because it doesn't want to replace a running app.  I usually start the download, then switch immediately to the springboard to watch it download.  If I see the clock dial on the app icon, then I know it's downloading.  Changing the bundle is not a good thing, not to mention not giving any user feedback when you tap "Install."

Answer (score 0):

As far as updating the app from the in app prompt.

It's a problem with apple/ios8.  They aren't exiting the app after the install.  If you quickly tap the home button after you hit install. Occasionally you will get  a successful download.

For future use you could find out a way to use exit which will kill the app but apple warns against using exit due to poor user experience. But if apple isn't providing a good user experience in the first place for this process I think this warrants the use imho.